# Linar algebra: dimension of intersection

Tags: linear-algebra

I suspect that $dim((U_1+U_2)\cap U_3)=dim(U_1\cap U_3)+dim(U_2\cap U_3)$ where $U_1$, $U_2$ and $U_3$ are vector spaces, but I couldn't find a proof or a counterexample. How could I proceed?

Comment: What if $U_1=U_2=U_3$? Can the two sides be still equal?

Comment: I didn't think the simplest counterexample, thanks